# linux PATH issue between /usr/bin/ and /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, path

Environment:

- linux novice :)
- tmux 1.1 was installed using apt-get
- tmux 1.6 was downloaded, configured, built, and installed from source
- tmux 1.1 was removed using apt-get

Problem:

- running tmux from path tries to run it from /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin

deets:

```
    wget http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tmux/tmux/tmux-1.6/tmux-1.6.tar.gz
    tar xvf tmux-1.6.tar.gz
    cd tmux-1.6/
    sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
    sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
    ./configure
    make
    make install
    ./tmux #version 1.6 worked perfectly
    cd ~
    tmux #ran old version as expected
    sudo apt-get remove tmux
```

results when I try to run it from ~:

```
    ~$tmux
    -bash: /usr/bin/tmux: No such file or directory
    ~$which tmux
    /usr/local/bin/tmux
    ~$echo $PATH
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: What do you get with `type -a tmux` -- there might be an alias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `hash -r` to flush the bash cache.